# Correct usage of "lest"

Tags: grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis

Which of the followings is/are the correct usage of the word "lest"? How are these different from each other?

1. ...hesitant to speak out lest he be fired.
2. ...hesitant to speak out lest he'd be fired.
3. ...hesitant to speak out lest he would/will be fired.

P.S. I took point number 1 as the reference for this question from the definition of lest from the Merriam-Webster Dictionary.
[image: Image is sourced from Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

Comment: it appears your question revolves around "he be, he would, he will" and does not have anything to do with lest

Comment: I'm with lbf.

Utkarsh Singh, how do you see the differences among:

"he be…" and
"he'd be…" and
"he would/will be fired"?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 would be most common, although they all are OK. There is no significant difference in meaning between them. 2 and 3 are somewhat awkward,

"Lest" is not used so much these days. People tend to find other ways of expressing the idea.

"Lest" as a conjunction may have entered English as a translation of a Norman French phrase (modern [French](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/a-moins-que/) *à moins que*, similar to [Spanish](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/a%20menos%20que) *a menos que*). Both the French and Spanish generally mean "unless". But "lest" may come from an Anglo-Saxon term of identical construction with the French and Spanish.

Sometimes "lest" has similar meaning to "unless", but is uncommon

> Lest we stay here until 5, we might be fired.
>
> Unless we stay here until 5, we might be fired.

I hope this helps.